# What does the 'where' clause within a trait do?

Tags: syntax, rust, traits, type-bounds

If I have this code:

```
trait Trait {
    fn f(&self) -> i32 where Self: Sized;

    fn g(&self) -> i32;
}


fn object_safety_dynamic(x: &Trait) {
    x.f();    // error 
    x.g();    // works
}
```

What does the `where` clause actually do?

Naively, I was thinking `where Self: Sized;` dictates something about the type implementing `Trait`, like 'if you implement `Trait` for type `A` your type `A` must be sized, i.e., it can be `i32` but not `[i32]`.

However, such a constraint would rather go as `trait Trait: Sized` (correct me if I am wrong)?

Now I noticed `where Self: Sized;` actually determines if I can call `f` or `g` from within `object_safety_dynamic`.

My questions:

1. What happens here behind the scenes?
2. What (in simple English) am I actually telling the compiler by `where Self: Sized;` that makes `g()` work but `f()` not?
3. In particular: Since `&self` is a reference anyway, what compiled difference exists between `f` and `g` for various (sized or unsized) types. Wouldn't it always boil down to something like `_vtable_f_or_g(*self) -> i32`, regardless of `where` or if the type is sized or not?
4. Why can I implement Trait for both `u8` and `[u8]`. Shouldn't the compiler actually stop me from implementing `f()` for `[u8]`, instead of throwing an error at the call site?

Comment: I think you got `f` and `g` the wrong way around. `x.g()` should work, while `x.f()` will be an error. That's because `f` is only defined for types that are `Sized`, but it is not guaranteed that `x` is `Sized` because not all `impl`s of `Trait` are.

Comment: Putting the constraint on the trait limits what types can implement the trait. Putting the constraint on the function inside the trait limits what implementing types can call the function.

Comment: @PeterHall, Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the where clause actually do?
>
> Naively, I was thinking where Self: Sized; dictates something about the type implementing Trait, like 'if you implement Trait for type A your type A must be sized, i.e., it can be i32 but not [i32].
>
> However, such a constraint would rather go as trait Trait: Sized

This is correct.

However, in this case, the bound applies only to the function. `where` bounds on functions are only checked at the callsite.

> What happens here behind the scenes?

There is a confusing bit about rust's syntax which is that `Trait` can refer to either

- The trait `Trait`; or
- The "trait object" `Trait`, which is actually a type, not an object.

`Sized` is a trait, and any type `T` that is `Sized` may have its size taken as a constant, by `std::mem::size_of::<T>()`. Such types that are not sized are `str` and `[u8]`, whose contents do not have a fixed size.

The type `Trait` is also unsized. Intuitively, this is because `Trait` as a type consists of all values of types that implement the trait `Trait`, which may have varying size. This means you can never have a value of type `Trait` - you can only refer to one via a "fat pointer" such as `&Trait` or `Box<Trait>` and so on. These have the size of 2 pointers - one for a vtable, one for the data. It looks roughly like this:

```
struct &Trait {
    pub data: *mut (),
    pub vtable: *mut (),
}
```

There is automatically an impl of the form:

```
impl Trait /* the trait */ for Trait /* the type */ {
    fn f(&self) -> i32 where Self: Sized { .. }
    fn g(&self) -> i32 {
        /* vtable magic: something like (self.vtable.g)(self.data) */
    }
}
```

> What (in simple English) am I actually telling the compiler by where Self: Sized; that makes g() work but f() not?

Note that since, as I mentioned, `Trait` is not `Sized`, the bound `Self: Sized` is not satisfied and so the function `f` cannot be called where `Self == Trait`.

> In particular: Since &self is a reference anyway, what compiled difference exists between f and g for various (sized or unsized) types. Wouldn't it always boil down to something like _vtable_f_or_g(*self) -> i32, regardless of where or if the type is sized or not?

The type `Trait` is *always* unsized. It doesn't matter which type has been coerced to `Trait`. The way you call the function with a `Sized` variable is to use it directly:

```
fn generic<T: Trait + Sized>(x: &T) { // the `Sized` bound is implicit, added here for clarity
    x.f();  // compiles just fine
    x.g();
}
```

> Why can I implement Trait for both u8 and [u8]. Shouldn't the compiler actually stop me from implementing f() for [u8], instead of throwing an error at the call site?

Because the trait is not bounded by `Self: Sized` - the function `f` is. So there is nothing stopping you from implementing the function - it's just that the bounds on the function can never be satisfied, so you can never call it.

Answer (score 5):

> `fn f(&self) -> i32 where Self: Sized;`

This says that `f` is only defined for types that also implement `Sized`. Unsized types may still implement `Trait`, but `f` will not be available.

Inside `object_safety_dynamic`, calling `x.f()` is actually doing: `(*x).f()`. While `x` is sized because it's a pointer, `*x` might not be because it could be *any* implementation of `Trait`. But code inside the function has to work for any valid argument, so you are not allowed to call `x.f()` there.